# Soap PHP Server with Python Client

Tags: python, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Does anyone know how to display in the server window the message received from the client?

Unfortunately, I can't find an example anywhere and when I use the print function, it unfortunately does not work.

**Server Code**:

```
    #===================================================================
{

    function strToHex($string){
    $hex = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
        }
    return strToUpper($hex);
    }
    $str = '';
    class PPRSrv {  
            public function simpleService($str){
                $str = (strToHex($str));
                print$str;
            }
        }

        #- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        session_start();
        $opt = array( 'uri' => 'http://10.0.2.15/SOAP/PHP2/srv.php' );
        $srv = new SoapServer( NULL, $opt );
        $srv->setClass('PPRSrv');
        while(1 == True){
            $srv->handle();

        }

    }
    #===================================================================
?>
```

**Client Code**:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://localhost/SOAP/PHP2/srv.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
print(client)
print("Podaj argument, ktory chcesz wyslac do serwera : ")
par1 = input()
result = client.service.simpleService(par1)
print("Wynik : ")
print(result)
```